# How to get the Knit directory of a current file programmatically?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

In the current version (1.2.5001) of RStudio, there are 2 ways to set the Knit directory (working directory for R Markdown files). See Fig. 1 and Fig. 2.

[image]

**Fig. 1** The global option to set the default Knit directory in RStudio.

[image]

**Fig. 2** The way to set the Knit directory for an individual file.

You can use the following code to retrieve the Global option from Fig. 1:

```r
.rs.readUiPref("knit_working_dir")
```

**The question:** how can the Knit directory of an individual file (which was set in Fig. 2) be retrieved programmatically?

Comment: Please give feedback about answers so the community knows whether the problem is solved or not

Answer (score 1):

Does this meet your needs?

```
dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path)
```

Comment: No, this does not return knit directory of the file.